# Retrieve data from database and store in string and bind all the strings to gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

i am extracting data from database into gridview with stored procedures. i dont want to specify the column names into datafeild attribute of boundfield in gridview. i want to extract all the columns into seperate strings in code behind and specify string name in datafield.

thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to dynamically create the `BoundField`s in code-behind using the column names returned from the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your `DataTable` returned from your stored procedure in the database, like this:

```
// Iterate through the columns of the DataTable to set the BoundFields dynamically
foreach (DataColumn theDataColumn in theDataTable.Columns)
{
    // Instantiate new BoundField
    BoundField theBoundField = new BoundField();

    // Set the DataField value
    theBoundField.DataField = theDataColumn.ColumnName;

    // Set the HeaderText value
    theBoundField.HeaderText = theDataColumn.ColumnName;

    // Add BoundField to the GridView
    GridView1.Columns.Add(theBoundField);
}
```